# I need to Convert from SQL Query into LINQ/Lambda Expression

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

I need to convert this sql statement into LINQ/Lambda Expression which I am unable to find online .Can anyone help with this

```
select  distinct o.ownerid ,a.acctnumber , c.cr_rpt_type_value ,c.cr_req_ts ,d.creditscore from Owner o 
inner join AcctOwner a
on o.ownerid =a.ownerid
left join (
select * from Cr_Rpt_Type x where x.cr_req_ts = (select MAX(cr_req_ts) from 
Cr_Rpt_Type y where 
x.cr_rpt_type_value= y.cr_rpt_type_value)) c on c.cr_rpt_type_value = o.ssn_vault_ref_number
left join Cr_Rpt_Type_dms d on d.Cr_Rpt_Rspn_id_dms = c.Cr_Rpt_Rspn_id
```

Comment: Can you provide some more info on why you want to do this? Dragging all the database data over to the client so that LINQ can perform an inefficient set of loops on it and discard possibly huge amounts of that data is potentially a huge waste of resources. LINQ is a hammer, and not every problem should be solved with a hammer

Comment: I am using entity framework (.Net core) where business requirement is that kind of only where I have to join 4 tables in my c# code from two different schema

Comment: You might up spending a long time coercing EF into generating the same sql that you have there, for the sake of slavish adherence to your business requirement..

Comment: @CaiusJard  i understand , can you help with the linq for these sql statements

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools to convert SQL statement to Linq like [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) or [Linquer](https://www.sqltolinq.com/).
these tools cover many types of SQL expressions.

But the thing is noticeable that

> Not every SQL statement can convert to Linq

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

I got the answer ,thanku

```
(from a in db.AcctOwner
join c in (
    (from x in db.Cr_Rpt_Type
    where
      x.Cr_req_ts ==
        (from y in db.Cr_Rpt_Type
        where
          x.Cr_rpt_type_value == y.Cr_rpt_type_value
        select new {
          y.Cr_req_ts
        }).Max(p => p.Cr_req_ts)
    select new {
      x
    })) on new { Cr_rpt_type_value = a.Owner.Ssn_vault_ref_number } equals new { Cr_rpt_type_value = c.x.Cr_rpt_type_value } into c_join
from c in c_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join d in db.Cr_Rpt_Type_dms on new { Cr_Rpt_Rspn_id_dms = c.x.Cr_Rpt_Rspn_id } equals new { Cr_Rpt_Rspn_id_dms = d.Cr_Rpt_Rspn_id_dms } into d_join
from d in d_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
  a.Acctnumber == Convert.ToString(5675771)
select new {
  a.Owner.Ownerid,
  a.Acctnumber,
  Cr_rpt_type_value = c.x.Cr_rpt_type_value,
  Cr_req_ts = c.x.Cr_req_ts,
  Creditscore = (int?)d.Creditscore
}).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AcctOwners
   .GroupJoin (
      Cr_Rpt_Types
         .Where (
            x => 
                  (x.Cr_req_ts == 
                     Cr_Rpt_Types
                        .Where (y => (x.Cr_rpt_type_value == y.Cr_rpt_type_value))
                        .Select (
                           y => 
                              new  
                              {
                                 Cr_req_ts = y.Cr_req_ts
                              }
                        )
                        .Max (p => p.Cr_req_ts)
                  )
         )
         .Select (
            x => 
               new  
               {
                  x = x
               }
         ), 
      a => 
         new  
         {
            Cr_rpt_type_value = a.Owner.Ssn_vault_ref_number
         }, 
      c => 
         new  
         {
            Cr_rpt_type_value = c.x.Cr_rpt_type_value
         }, 
      (a, c_join) => 
         new  
         {
            a = a, 
            c_join = c_join
         }
   )
   .SelectMany (
      temp0 => temp0.c_join.DefaultIfEmpty (), 
      (temp0, c) => 
         new  
         {
            temp0 = temp0, 
            c = c
         }
   )
   .GroupJoin (
      Cr_Rpt_Type_dms, 
      temp1 => 
         new  
         {
            Cr_Rpt_Rspn_id_dms = temp1.c.x.Cr_Rpt_Rspn_id
         }, 
      d => 
         new  
         {
            Cr_Rpt_Rspn_id_dms = d.Cr_Rpt_Rspn_id_dms
         }, 
      (temp1, d_join) => 
         new  
         {
            temp1 = temp1, 
            d_join = d_join
         }
   )
   .SelectMany (
      temp2 => temp2.d_join.DefaultIfEmpty (), 
      (temp2, d) => 
         new  
         {
            temp2 = temp2, 
            d = d
         }
   )
   .Where (temp3 => (temp3.temp2.temp1.temp0.a.Acctnumber == Convert.ToString (5675771)))
   .Select (
      temp3 => 
         new  
         {
            Ownerid = temp3.temp2.temp1.temp0.a.Owner.Ownerid, 
            Acctnumber = temp3.temp2.temp1.temp0.a.Acctnumber, 
            Cr_rpt_type_value = temp3.temp2.temp1.c.x.Cr_rpt_type_value, 
            Cr_req_ts = temp3.temp2.temp1.c.x.Cr_req_ts, 
            Creditscore = (Int32?)(temp3.d.Creditscore)
         }
   )
   .Distinct ()
```